# TextView sometimes loses contents on configuration change or Home button

Tags: java, android

A `TextView` is slowly filled with text coming from a background service. I have overridden the `onSaveInstanceState`() and `onRestoreInstanceState`() methods in `MainActivity` and added the `android:freezesText="true"` attribute to the `TextView` in the layout. In most cases the contents of the `TextView` are preserved when the device is rotated or the app is minimized, pressing the Home button, and another app is started. However, now and then the contents are lost. Since it is slowly collected by the background service it cannot be recovered easily and valuable information is lost.

I’m testing the app on a device with Android 7.0 but I also distributed it to other devices with different Android versions and it works fine, except for these occasional info losses.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView textView;
    static private boolean firstRun = true;

    private final BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
            if (bundle != null) {
                String newPost = bundle.getString(MyService.POST);
                textView.append((new Date()).toString().substring(11, 19) + " " + newPost + "\n");
                // Delete 250 leading chars if too many
                Editable ed = textView.getEditableText();
                int len = ed.length();
                if( len > 5000 ) ed.delete(0, 250);
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        textView = findViewById(R.id.idTextView);
        if( firstRun ) {
            firstRun = false;
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
            startService(intent);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle  savedInstanceState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        savedInstanceState.putCharSequence("TEXTVIEW", textView.getText());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        CharSequence viewContents = savedInstanceState.getCharSequence("TEXTVIEW");
        textView.setText(viewContents);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(MyService.NOTIFICATION));
    }
}
```

I've read a lot of posts about similar problems and I have done everything I know about to avoid it.

**EDIT**: I've added attribute `android:configChanges` to `Activity` in the manifest. `onCreate ()` is now called only once. Nevertheless, the `TextView` contents are sometimes lost due to app **restart**. It happens only when the app is redrawn, at reconfiguration or when it's taken to foreground. Why is it restarted? Logcat in Android Studio reports no problems.

Comment: Try to add the `onPause()` and insert the `unregisterReceiver(receiver)` call.

Comment: Thank you Graziano for this suggestion. Could you explain how this affects the contents of `TextView` when the device is rotated or the app is hidden by another one ? As pointed out in another comment, it is quite difficult to verify a solution.

Comment: In your code you have 3 elements that can change your `EditText` during the rotation: the `BroadcastReceiver`, the attribute `android:freezesText="true"`, and the methods `onSave/RestoreInstanceState`. My suggestion is to stop the first (here my previous suggestion), but I suggest also to remove the second one (the freezesText attribute), in order to leave bunden and honor of the task to `onSave/RestoreInstanceState`.

Comment: @Graziano OK, it is easy to remove `freezesText` and to add `unregisterReceiver`. I can try it. But, honestly, the receiver only appends more text and I think `freezesText` does not do anything because I never call `onSaveInstanceState` and `onRestoreInstanceState` on TextView. But again, I have no idea why/when it happens so it is very difficult to verify. I will never be sure it is solved.

Comment: @Graziano Adding `unregisterReceiver()` proved quite necessary to avoid memory leak, but it didn't solve the disappearing text. I believe that `onRestoreInstanceState()` isn't called in some cases, but I don't know when or why. The loss of text in `TextView` occurs seldom, but it does occur. I've also added `onRestoreInstanceState()` to `onCreate()`, but it didn't do any good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The loss of `TextView` contents occurs when Android occasionally destroys Activity when in the background, and recreates it when the app is taken to foreground. In this scenario, in the call to `onCreate()`  `Bundle savedInstanceState` is `null` and cannot be used to restore the `TextView`. However, static variables in Activity are preserved.

**SOLUTION**: To keep the `TextView` contents in this destroy-create transition save the contents in a static variable in `onSaveInstanceState()` and restore in `onCreate()`.  In this scenario `onRestoreInstanceState()` is never called and cannot be used.

I verified this solution on a device with Android 7.0. Other Android versions may behave differently. It is a pity that Android is so poorly documented.

Answer (score 0):

you use shared preference

For gradle

```
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.8'
```

Initialise the Shared Preference

```
SharedPreferences  mPrefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Save data or any object and class

```
MyObject myObject = new MyObject;
Editor prefsEditor = mPrefs.edit();
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(myObject);
prefsEditor.putString("MyObject", json);
prefsEditor.commit();
```

Get Data

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = mPrefs.getString("MyObject", "");
MyObject obj = gson.fromJson(json, MyObject.class);
```

Comment: You can save data in different ways, e.g. using a file, which I'm more familiar with. But using `Bundle savedInstanceState` is the recommended solution and should work. I don't think `savedInstanceState` is lost, there must be another explanation.

Answer (score 0):

check also `Bundle` passed as argument to `onCreate` method

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ... your code
    checkInstanceState(savedInstanceState); // at the end after GUI init
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    checkInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}


private void checkInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (savedInstanceState==null) return;
    CharSequence viewContents = savedInstanceState.getCharSequence("TEXTVIEW");
    textView.setText(viewContents);
}
```

Comment: Observe that `savedInstanceState` cannot be null in `onRestoreInstanceState`, see the docs. I might add restoring `TextView` in `onCreate` but `onRestoreInstanceState` comes later and overrides it. It is very difficult to verify the solution since the problem occurs seldom and I don't know how to  provoke it.